# calc() doesn't calc in CSS, differences in browsers

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I created two tables, and I want to set the `width` of the right 3 columns depending on the size of the first one. I tried `calc((100% - 200px)/3)` but it doesn't work in all browsers: Firefox 40 fails, IE11 fails, and Chrome 44 seems to do it right. How can I do it so that `calc()` is understood in all browsers? Or should I just forget it?

I created a much simpler version that fails just as well.

```
<table class="tableauTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="tableauRow first">
        <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" class="tableauCell first"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Objet - Acteurs</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Julien GARDIN</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Justine VINCLAIR</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Marcel COMMAS</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="tableauRow first">
        <th colspan="3" header="" class="tableauCell first"></th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Julien GARDIN</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Justine VINCLAIR</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Marcel COMMAS</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

The same, with `calc()`:

```
<table class="tableauTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="tableauRow first">
        <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" class="tableauCell first"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Objet - Acteurs</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Julien GARDIN</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Justine VINCLAIR</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Marcel COMMAS</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="tableauRow first">
        <th colspan="3" header="" class="tableauCell first"></th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Julien GARDIN</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Justine VINCLAIR</span>
        </th>
        <th class="tableauCell header col3x"><span class="xspTextComputedField">Marcel COMMAS</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

The CSS:

```
    .tableauTable {
        width:100%;
        border-spacing: 1px;
    }
    .tableauRow.first .tableauCell {
        background: #d2d2d2 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tableauCell.first {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .tableauCell.col3 {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .tableauCell.col3x {
        width: calc(30%);
    }
    .tableauCell.first {
        background: #d2d2d2 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tableauCell {
        background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 2px solid white;
        color: black;
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjefb/19vrf52o/

Comment: It seams that it's not a browser-compatibility issue [though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific regarding what "fails" means?  It doesn't layout as you expect?  The layout gets ignored?  It crashed the browser?  According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc there can be issued caused by how different browsers handle subpixels.

Comment: Did you open the fiddle? You'll see that when the col3 width is set to 30%, all browsers behave correctly, whereas when the width is set to calc(30%) only Chrome seems to work.

Comment: @D.Bugger I have updated my answer for you. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, using *table-layout: fixed* and, in order to fix column sizes, I used colgroup and col tags. Now calc() seems to behave, that is to say: the leftmost column has a fixed width and all other columns are equally sized.

Thanks all, for thinking with me!

Comment: Pleased you got it sorted.

Answer (score 4):

why are you trying to calc a single value? `calc(30%);`

calc is very picky about syntax, particularly the gaps between resource values. **You need to add spaces** :

```
width: calc((100% - 200px) / 3);
                 ^^^^    ^^^^^
```

Edit: This seems not to be the issue, instead approach that the width value **is** being applied to the cell (because firebug shows it is), but is different depending on cell contents, so this shows that the width value is being over-ridden, so try setting some other values:

in the table and the cell CSS definitions set:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not relevant: there are spaces around the minus, and the slash doesn't require them. As I said, I presented a much simpler version, with a trivial calc expression, and even that goes wrong.

Comment: @D.Bugger Firebug shows your width value (`30%`) is being applied, but perhaps you should try to set the `min-width` to 30%. Because width value can be over-ruled by other elements in the hiarachy

Comment: I'm going to try to use _table-layout: fixed_

Comment: Yes. When you use `table-layout:fixed`,  *"Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells"*. So, in your use-case you have to use a fixed layout (in addition to what Martin says above). You also need to take into account that `2px` border and `1px` border-spacing. It will make a difference of `11px` overall. Then, it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/19vrf52o/6/ (check dev tools)